# Routed events in silverlight 3?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, delegates, routed-events

I have a Control, within a control, within a control.

Like so..

QuizMaster -> Question -> Answers -> RadioButton

When one of the answers is checked I want the function in Quizmaster called AskNextQuestion() to run.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create an event in your nested control, and have your `QuizMaster` subscribe to that event.

In your `Answers` add this:

```
public static event Action<bool> IsAnswered;
```

and Fire this event when you select a `RadioButton` in its handler

```
public void OnRadioButtonSelected(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)
{
  if(IsAnswered != null)
    IsAnswered(true);
}
```

and in your `QuizMaster` Subscribe to this static event:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
  Answers.IsAnswered += new Action<bool>(Answers_IsAnsweredCompleted);
}

public void Answers_IsAnsweredCompleted(bool IsAsnwered)
{
  //call your method in QuizMaster
}
```

Comment: Even if QuizMaster has no knowledge of Answers, only Question does.

Comment: May have solved the user's problem, but it does not actually implement a routed event.